# Table data doesn't match database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, tableau-api

I am now creating a Tableau report from MySQL database. However the data shown in Tableau report doesn't match the data in the database.

In the database I have a table which has columns:

1. Timeouts ---------- only 0 or 1 which represents True or False
2. Date_Value  ---------- in Date type
3. Session_id  ---------- in String
4. Device_Brand ---------- Strings like Google or Apple

Now in Tableau I have a Calculated Field named "Unique_User", which has the formula:

```
countd(case [IsTO] when true then (STR([Date Value]) + "-" + [Session Id]) end)
```

where [IsTo] is:

```
if([Timeouts]=1, TRUE, FALSE)
```

In the report, after clicking the brank "Google", the value of Unique_User is 1312. If I replace distinct count "countd" with "count", the value will be 2061.

However, if I directly run query in the database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_VALUE, '%d %m %Y'),'-', SESSION_ID)) AS USER_COUNT from test_agoop_details WHERE DEVICE_BRAND='Google' and TIMEOUTS_3G=1
```

even though I used DISTINCT COUNT, the result will always be 2061.

I was wondering if the string concatenation in Tableau created some duplicate strings? Does anyone have some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Don't know about mysql, but in sqlserver, if you want to count distincts the syntax is: COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(...)). Does that make any difference?

Comment: I believe @HoneyBadger (I envy your nickname so much!) got it. COUNT(DISTINCT...) is different from DISTINCT COUNT(...)

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yeah you are right, the two statements are different and COUNT(DISTINCT ...) got the correct result. How come? I will read the docs... Thank you very much!

Comment: Count distinct can be expensive for large datasets. You *might* see a bit of a performance gain if you can move Timeouts=1 to the filter shelf  in Tableau (which generates a where clause), and then simplify your calculated field to just "Str[Date Value] + "-" + [Session Id]", call it User_Id say, with a countd as the aggregation applied in Tableau. That is  - don't hard code the aggregation function in the calculated field if you don't have to. Gives you more flexibility inside Tableau.

Comment: Of course, if you move Timeouts=1 to the filter shelf then all the data on that worksheet will have that filter applied. So whether you can do that or not depends on what other values you need on that worksheet, or whether they can be moved to another sheet.